# Upload file in aix server from spring boot application deployed in windows

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, file-upload, aix, application.properties

I have a spring boot application deployed as service in windows and connected to remote oracle database located in aix server. In my application i have to upload files that will be stored in the main aix server but not in oracle partition, in something like "/file/image". I think i have to add something in my application.properties but i dont know what exactly,
Someoane can help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

From within Oracle database you can use UTL_FILE package: https://www.oratable.com/utl_file/
But looks like you need SSH, SFTP/FTP or Samba share